# Is the R2 statistic affected by normalizing your timeseries?

Tags: time-series, r-squared

I  have been trying on comparing to time series, one predicted and one measured. One of the first and most simplistic statistics that can help is R2. I have no issues calculating R2 but my supervisor suggested to first normalize both time series such that the daily trend is removed and then calculate the R2.

I am wondering whether normalising the time series will affect the R2.

Note: with normalising, I mean that I have a third time series that I use to devide the other two time series with. So in a more abstract way. I started with time series t1 and t2, than I decided both timeseries by time series t3 giving time series t4 (=t1/t3) and t5 (=t2/t3). Now my question is: Is the R2 of t1 and t2 the same as the R2 of t4 and t5?

Comment: Is "removing the daily trend" really called "normalizing"?  "Detrending" seems easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the same.  To take an extreme case, suppose `t1` and `t2` are both equal to `t3` with small amounts of independent noise.  The correlation between `t1` and `t2` will be close to 1, but the correlation between `t4` and `t5` will be close to zero.

As a practical example, suppose `t1` and `t2` are prices of two unrelated goods and `t3` is the consumer price index.  The two prices will be correlated positively over time because of inflation, but their inflation-adjusted prices might be correlated positively or negatively or not at all.

Comment: +1 Try $t_1=(10,11,12,13)$ and $t_2=(1000,1331,1728, 2197)$ and $t_3=(100,121,144,169)$, the geometric mean of the previous two.  Then $R^2$ for $t_1$ and $t_2$ is beyond $0.99$ while $R^2$ for $t_4$ and $t_5$ is beyond $-0.99$